# Why does VS Code's JavaScript syntax highlighting differ when using 'var'?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

As you can see below, in some instances it highlights green, in others it is white. Does it have to do with the difference between regular function expressions, and those which are immediately invoked?

I have noticed this effect with the majority of color themes available in Visual Studio Code.

[image]

Comment: Green are functions and white are objects? lol

Comment: I think it has to do with capitalization; the function names you capitalized are green. This is probably because capitalized function names usually indicate constructors.

Comment: Thanks for the swift replies. I included an extended screenshot to show that it's not just capitalised function names.

Comment: @devgeist The plot thickens... is the bottom one the same color green though?

Comment: @Delvian It is! Should've included it in my original post. If I remove the IIFE parentheses from the first line (well the first parenthesis), `budgetController` turns green.

Answer (score 6):

Identifiers with names which begin with capital letters are conventionally reserved for constructor functions / classes.

This is what you are using them for. Your syntax highlighter is distinguishing based on the type of value assigned to them.

[image: screenshot]